# Get the place for the user entries

Tags: php, mysql

I am really not good at math, but can someone help me though how i can get the place the user has on all entries? Etc. "You are now number 43 out of 20.403.044 entries"?

`SELECT ?myPlace? FROM entries WHERE userid = 1 ORDER BY time ASC`

Comment: your really not good at writing questions either - no idea what you are asking

Comment: do you know about COUNT in mysql?

Comment: I know count yes, but cannot figure out how to find the entry number that the user has. I can find all entries count, but now the place of a specific userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL lacks [windowing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29#Window_function). Therefore you have emulate them. One way to do it is something like this

```sql
SELECT userid,
(
  SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) 
    FROM entries 
   WHERE time < e.time
) place
  FROM entries e
 WHERE userid = 1
```

Sample output:

```
| USERID | PLACE |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |     2 |
```

If you need total number of entries in the same query

```sql
SELECT userid,
(
  SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) 
    FROM entries 
   WHERE time < e.time
) place,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM entries
) total
  FROM entries e
 WHERE userid = 1;
```

Sample output:

```
| USERID | PLACE | TOTAL |
|--------|-------|-------|
|      1 |     2 |     5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78a9e/4)** demo

Answer (score 1):

ok, i think you want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE id <= YOUR_USER_ID
```

Comment: I am not sure, but since the original query is ordered by `time ASC`, I think he wants the rank of a certain User ID based on it's time (like the rank in a race).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rank with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM entries entries1
INNER JOIN entries entries2 ON (entries1.id != entries2.id AND entries2.time < entries1.time)
WHERE entries1.id = 4
```

You just need to count the number of people with a better time, and add 1 (since the first rank is 1).